# How to remove a Client event listener?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a `<Client>.on` function and I want to stop the listening of this event, example:

```
bot.on('messageCreate', message => {
  // some code
});
```

How to stop it and not receive this event anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `bot` is an instance of [`Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client), which extends Node.js' [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter). You can listen to an event (for example `message` or `ready`) using [`on`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener) and remove that listener using [`off`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_off_eventname_listener). `addListener` and `removeListener` are also aliases of `on` and `off` respectively.

Store the listener function in a variable, and when you need to remove that listener use `bot.off(eventName, listener)`:

```js
const listener = () => {
  // your code here...
}

bot.on('event', listener)

// When you need to remove the listener:
bot.off('event', listener)
```

Comment: This worked at the start but it waas causing some error which caused my bot to crash

Comment: @SciscorX Could you please edit your question to include the error?

Comment: What would you do if you needed to pass information to the listener? Moreover, suppose you have multiple instances of 'client' running (such as a bot operating on two servers). As it is, the listener would register events from ALL servers, not just one. Thus, if 'event' occurred on Server A, it would trigger in both servers. How would you manage keeping listeners separate for each server?

Comment: @J.Day I'm not quite sure what you mean. If you wanted something to run only on particular guilds (servers), you could put `if (message.guild.id !== 'some ID') return` (for example). before the rest of the code in your listener. If you have more questions, feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You ran into an issue I was troubleshooting myself, trying to filter events per each server and I finally had figured it out.
In this instance I am using the bot object rather than client. But this is how you can filter a singular event per server, just add onto the if/else statements. I am only going to note the method for the channelCreate, but the concept applies to most of the events you can listen to. In the documentation it noted that channel types are integers, but in my debugging it showed them as a string. On the if statement line, the method works by checking where the creation channel resides in (guild it was created in), if that matches your criteria then it continues.

```js
bot.on("channelCreate", (channel) => {
    if(channel.guild.id == "######"){
        if(channel.type == 4 || channel.type == "category"){
            console.log(`Category Created: ID: ${channel.id} Name: ${channel.name}`)
        }
        else if(channel.type == 0 || channel.type == "text"){
            console.log(`Channel Created: ID: ${channel.id} Name: ${channel.name}`)
        }
    }
    else if (channel.guild.id == "######"){
      //do other stuff
    }
});
```

#### Links:

Discord Documentation that lists events:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client

A nice github gist to see functions:
https://gist.github.com/koad/316b265a91d933fd1b62dddfcc3ff584

Channel Types:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelType
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#channel-object-channel-types