# How to remove event listeners in JS / DiscordJS v13

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js, javascript-objects

I'm currently using discordJS and I'm need of manually removing event listeners. I've found them in client._events. However logging this I get this:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  shardDisconnect: [Function (anonymous)],
  interactionCreate: [ [AsyncFunction (anonymous)], [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] ]
}
```

I'd assume this Object was being made with Object.create(null) . I just can't seem to get the values from interactionCreate. Anyone know how that works?

Comment: Have you tried, `client.off(eventName, listener)`.

Comment: Oh that worked. I just see it extends Node.js EventEmitter too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop a specific bot.on function Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62684329/how-to-stop-a-specific-bot-on-function-discord-js)